# Calculating point distance in separate X/Y-values (lengths of opposite side and adjacent side) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, distance, proximity

**Description:**

I have to position a temporary `initial zero point` into a corner of my map. Afterwards I want to calculate the geometric distance between many different points and this so called `initial zero point`.

---

**The challenge is:**

I don't need the `nearest distance` (shortest way) between those points, but the X and Y-components of those distances separately (= lengths of `opposite side` and `adjacent side`).

How can I solve that? The `nearest distance` won't work in my case, because it already shows the hypotenuse distance instead of `opposite side` and `adjacent side` lengths.

[image: Schemes of distance measurements in ArcGIS (not useful, because no output of separate X/Y-data)]

---

**One possible approach:**

Creating a small coordinate system with two lines (X and Y), which are heading through the previous `initial zero point`. Afterwards I could calculate the distance from those already mentioned points to these lines. As a result, I will get distance-data for X and Y components separately.

---

Are there any other, maybe more comfortable ways how to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this just using the GUI or via ArcPy?  If it is using ArcPy then can you include a code snippet to show what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: Near with location gives you all you need at least for points.